# How do I capture an event from an ALB for a lambda function and extract the "host" from it?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a lambda on edge function that receives a cloudfront event and uses the "host" to perform a dynamo db lookup. Below is the snippet of code that receives the cf event.

```
    function main(event, context, callback) {        
      **const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;**
      const headers = request.headers;
      const host = headers.host[0].value;

  };
```

I am trying to replace cloudfront with an ALB. I am relatively new to node.js and struggling with 
 capturing the event from the ALB( incoming http or https request) and extracting the host from it. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    function main(event, context, callback) {
      **const request = event;**
      const headers = request.headers;
      const host = headers.host[0].value
}
```

Here is an example Event from an Application Load Balancer (from the aws documentation)

```
{
    "requestContext": {
        "elb": {
            "targetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:123456789012:targetgroup/lambda-279XGJDqGZ5rsrHC2Fjr/49e9d65c45c6791a"
        }
    },
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "path": "/lambda",
    "queryStringParameters": {
        "query": "1234ABCD"
    },
    "headers": {
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "host": "lambda-alb-123578498.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-5c536348-3d683b8b04734faae651f476",
        "x-forwarded-for": "72.12.164.125",
        "x-forwarded-port": "80",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
        "x-imforwards": "20"
    },
    "body": "",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`event.headers.host` will give you the host.

Comment: Thank you so much @LostJon. Will the event be captured like so const request = event ?

Comment: looks to be that way! You should try it out to be sure.